# Sliding Scale Pricing

Tags: civimember, price-sets

I am trying to set up a membership option where people can pay what they can with a minimum amount set.  For example $60 rather than the standard $180 for a membership. I would have thought this was possible/easy because you can do that with contributions but I do not see a way to assign a membership to the contribution.

All I need is a text field for people to type in the number just like on contribution price sets.

Is there an extension that does this? Is there an easy way with code? CiviRules (I looked but I do not see a good way to tell what PriceSet field it came from)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a text box to choose membership amount but there are two ways as a workaround

1. Create a price set with required pricefields

   a) Select or Radio button with Membership as 0 fees

   b) Add text price field with $1 amount.
2. Make membership type fee as 0 and include contribution amount section on contribution page
   [image]

Comment: Thank you! That will work well overall but is there an extension to make the membership fee field required if the $0 membership is selected?  Like Drupal Conditional Fields.